# Reimporting exchanges in cryptofeed

Tags: python, cryptofeed

I have to reimport some exchanges that I have imported this way:

```
from cryptofeed.exchange import Coinbase
```

I have tried with `importlib`, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Importing does not "bring in" the data.  It just lets you access the APIs.  Re-importing will do nothing at all.  What is the real problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I use them to check if a new crypto has been added, but it only detects new ones when its imported. If a new crypto is added while its running it wont say nothing until the program is stopped and started again.

Comment: Looking at the source code, I see you are right.  But since adding another crypto requires downloading an update, I have to think that forcing your script to restart is the best way to handle this.  Otherwise, you'll have stale objects hanging around with code that is outdated, and YOUR code will have no idea how to create the new objects.  It's not terribly difficult to restart yourself.

Comment: I have been trying to avoid the restart, the code not only checks the cryptos, it will be very incovinient to have to restart it.

Comment: Let's say they add a new class `BabyCrypto`.  How will your code know how to handle that?  How can you create a new object of that type?

Comment: Im not trying to track the exchanges, but the cryptocurrencies in some of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if a new crypto has been added, call `Coinbase.symbols(refresh=True)`. This will re-query the exchange for an up to date symbol mapping and return that list to the caller.